# Solr: the search results per category with only one query

Tags: solr, split, categories

I want to show the search results per category:

Example:

Category 1

10 objects

Category 2

10 objects

Category 3

10 objects

...

Now I make one query per category, but this approach is to slow (very many queries).
Can I get this results with only one query?

Comment: You want have exact results divided by category? Or only counts matter? (10 in your example)

Comment: I want exact results divided by category.

Comment: why not just select everything, and then traverse through result list to gather objects and divide them by category?

Comment: Your approach is impossible, because I sort the results by relevance and I need at least 10 results in each category.

If I make "limit 10", so I get  only 10 results from some categories, but not from all categories.

Comment: Don't restrict rows to 10. Just traverse your results page by page and accumulate objects in your category. End this process when all categories will have 10 results or you meet the end of result list

Comment: I have many millions objects in solr index, so is "limit" necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for grouping:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

Comment: This idea is good, but I use the Field Collapsing by one field. So I cannot use Result Grouping together.

Comment: I though you have "category" field and then you want to get 10 results per category (matching your query). Field Collapsing is the same thing as grouping. Can you add request you are making at the moment, please?

Comment: I have the objects in solr index with the field "oid"- this is not category field. I make group results on this field to avoid some duplicates.